# How can I include windows WexTestClass.h in a c++ project

Tags: windows, visual-studio, unit-testing, windows-10

I've been trying to find this header file everywhere. This is part if Microsoft's Unit Test API, that doesn't seem to be very well documented.

All I know is that I need to download and install the Windows Driver Kit, which I have, but where do I find this header file and all associated include files for this project? 
I have Visual Studio 2017 and Windows and Driver Kits 10.0.15063.468 respectively

I checked C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.15063.0 but that header is not there, it doesn't automatically get recognized by visual studio either.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found it under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Testing\Development\inc`